# SugarOrm and MultiDex

Tags: java, android, android-multidex, sugarorm

I developed an app and I used sugarORM for database. It was working fine till I started use MultiDex. After that, I couldn't create new tables. Actually I did but It crashed ever time. I get this error.

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: HAVA_DURUMU_ORM
```

### My application class

```
public class Application47 extends com.orm.SugarApp {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       SugarContext.init(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

- I tired not overriding onCreate method but same error.

### Here is how I give subclass to my app.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:name=".Application47">
```

- I tried giving exact package "com.lior.izuapp.Application47" it didn't help.

I tried cleaning project, but it didn't work. So I delete app from device and reinstall to device. Then All the tables were gone. There was like no database.

I couldn't find solution in web. Is there anybody know how to handle with this?

Comment: You got "no such table" after you re-created the database?

Comment: After I started use MultiDex.

Comment: Why do you need Multidex?

Comment: I need MultiDex to use googlemaps. Without it I get 64K Limit. When I search it I found this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: compile using API 23, which natively supports multidex (because of ART Runtime).

Comment: Try to increase the version of your database in the Manifest.xml